# Canonical and Alternate/hreflang Website Tags - Is this correct? Trying to understand placement of Hreftag for two separate (same) websites

Tags: html, web, canonical-link, alternate, hreflang

**Environment:** I have two websites being eg. www.website.**com** and www.website.**com.au**. The .com is for a USA audience and the .com.au is for an Australian audience. These two websites are a part of the same company, with the same domain names, just like google.com and google.com.au for example. Though, they are both two separate websites which are hosted on two different servers, essentially two separate entities. They do have similar, and at times, exact same content on both websites since it's all the one company.

I coded so that each page **automatically** gets canonical and alternate tags **based on the URL** (so this is dynamic), and referring to each website, it is set up like this for example:

**Australian website:**

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.website.com.au/page1">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-AU" href="https://www.website.com.au/page1" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-US" href="https://www.website.com/page1" />
```

**USA website:**

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.website.com/page1">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-US" href="https://www.website.com/page1" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-AU" href="https://www.website.com.au/page1" />
```

**Question:** Is this a correct set up? For each website I have placed an alternate and href tag for the native website under each Canonical tag.

**Eg**. AU Canonical with AU alternate underneath, and vice versa for the USA website.

Should I be adding an AU alternate Tag for the Australian website, and adding a USA alternate tag for the USA website?

*Note: I have tried looking into the best practice for this environment set up and situation, but I cannot find a clear answer for SEO regarding the alternate and hreflang tags.
*

Kind regards,
Neuc

Comment: Your implementation is absolutely correct. I recommend you to stick with it. I strongly recommend supplementing the current implementation with the x-default annotation, which recommends an alternative in case the user is not targeted by any of the specified annotations. This annotation may use the US link as the default global market. This way you get the most out of the Hreflang mechanism for SEO purposes. The result would be:
`<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://www.website.com/page1" />`